# How to rewrite a letter in a file containing multiple lines in Qt?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, file-io, qfile

I have a file which contains numerous lines each being a sentence in english.
What my program has to do is: I have to change a letter in one of those lines.

File looks like this:

```
he has wild dreams  
he walks into the forest alone  
he transforms into a bear
```

If i have to change the letter 'e' in "the" of the 2nd line, how do i do it in Qt??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the file line by line (using [`QFile::readLine()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qiodevice.html#readLine-2)), and add it to a QStringList.

```
while (file.canReadLine())
    list.append(file.readLine());
```

Then you could make the changes in the QStringList and output it to the same file.